# Matching user email with PayPal email from IPN

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm configuring a PayPal IPN listener from [this](http://www.micahcarrick.com/paypal-ipn-with-php.html) tutorial and [ipnlistener.php](https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN/blob/master/ipnlistener.php).

When I need a user to pay, I show him this form

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" 
    method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<? echo $myPaypalEmail; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Digital Download">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<? echo $price; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="THIS URL">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="myhost.com/ipn.php">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
        border="0" name="submit">
</form>
```

Following the guide, I correctly receive a POST request to the file `ipn.php`. I receive a lot of useful data about the payment but my problem is: **how can I know which user made the payment?**

A "user" is a person registering on my website, giving me personal informations and his/her email address. How can I connect these informations to the POST request I receive back from PayPal? The email used to register on my website may be different from the one used in PayPal.

I can think of 2 solutions:

a) Place a unique user id in the return URL, parse it with $_GET and then... This could hardly solve the problem.

b) Get the payment ID as soon as the transaction starts. But I have no idea on how to do that.

As you can see, my problem is to associate a user with the transaction id. The workflow is:

```
HTML Form -> Paypal website -> ipn.php
```

HTML Form has user info while ipn.php receive transaction info: **I need the user info to go into ipn.php** in order to check if the total has been correctly paid and to perform stuff on the user account. How can I do this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also pass the user ID in the "custom" field.  This can be literally anything you want, up to 255 characters.  This gets passed to Paypal and is sent in the IPN response as well.  I use this field to distinguish between my various databases when I am storing IPN data.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="UNIQUE_USER_ID">
```

`item_number` allows to pass any arbitrary numeric values back and forth. I can use this to identify the user from the payment. `$_POST['item_number']` will allow to see this value in the `ipn.php` file.